# What is the effect of ticking "This is a bot account" in Mastodon?

Tags: bots, mastodon

If I edit my profile I get the option to mark my account as a bot account:

[image: This is a bot account. This account mainly performs automated actions and might not be monitored.]

Currently the Mastodon documentation mentions the attribute, but doesn't explain what effect it has:

- https://docs.joinmastodon.org/api/entities/#account
- https://docs.joinmastodon.org/api/authentication/

This bot guide mentions the setting, but again doesn't explain what it does:

- https://botwiki.org/resource/tutorial/how-to-make-a-mastodon-botsin-space-app-bot/

How is this signal communicated in machine-facing transmission and/or human-facing UX? What are the implications (e.g. toots won't appear in *some context*)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After checking the [source code](https://github.com/tootsuite/mastodon):

- Shows a 'bot' badge where user/moderator/admin badges would be shown
  ([app/helpers/stream_entries_helper.rb](https://github.com/tootsuite/mastodon/blob/e3b39ea4a41ea7fb0e2ef19a84056e9f835f7c8a/app/helpers/stream_entries_helper.rb#L37)).
- Does not contribute to "trending tags" statistics
  ([app/models/trending_tags.rb](https://github.com/tootsuite/mastodon/blob/e3b39ea4a41ea7fb0e2ef19a84056e9f835f7c8a/app/models/trending_tags.rb#L12)).
- ActivityPub actor record has [type](https://www.w3.org/TR/activitystreams-vocabulary/#actor-types) "Service" instead of "Person"
  ([app/serializers/activitypub/actor_serializer.rb](https://github.com/tootsuite/mastodon/blob/e3b39ea4a41ea7fb0e2ef19a84056e9f835f7c8a/app/serializers/activitypub/actor_serializer.rb#L45)).

  (How the actor record is interpreted depends on the receiving site. Mastodon itself recognizes incoming "Service" records as a bot account. Pleroma currently does not distinguish between different types at all.)